# Display list of users with a specific role to guest users

Tags: 8, views, users

Some users on my Drupal 8 site have the role of 'Champion'. I have created a views block that lists out all the users with this role. It shows the list correctly when I am logged in as an admin, but does not display any results to guest users. It appears that the 'View user information' permission, which I have assigned to guest users does not allow viewing of user's roles ( I can see why from a security point of view).

Can anyone suggest how I can get this list of users to display for guest (unauthenticated) users? Either how I could override the permissions, or another approach?

Comment: To clarify, 'Access' is set to 'permission: view user information' - and I have assigned this permission to unauthenticated users. I have also tried changing this to none. The key thing here is that as soon as I add in  the following filter criteria, guest users can no longer see the results:

`User: Roles (= Champion)`

Comment: Did you try disabling SQL query rewriting in the view settings?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please check this setting, Also check the user permission.

Comment: Thanks, but I have checked those things. I've added in a clarification in a comment above.